# How to detect swiping left / right on the iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Is there any easy way to detect these kinds of gestures for iPhone?
I can use touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded. But how can I implement the gestures? thz u.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are on the right track. In touchesBegan you should store the position where the user first touches the screen.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    self.startPosition = [touch locationInView:self];
}
```

Similar code in touchesEnded gives you the final position. By comparing the two positions you can determine the direction of movement. If the x-coordinate has moved beyond a certain tolerance you have a left or right swipe.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; 
    CGPoint endPosition = [touch locationInView:self];

    if (startPosition.x < endPosition.x) {
        // Right swipe
    } else {
        // Left swipe
    }
}
```

You do not need touchesMoved unless you want to detect and track a swipe while the user is still touching the screen. It may also be worth testing that the user has moved a minimal distance before deciding they have performed a swipe.

Comment: can i use it for UITableview?

Comment: This is pretty outdated, using `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` is much cleaner (iOS 9)

Answer (score 36):

You will using UISwipeGestureRecognizer Object to detect the Touch and direction of Swipe In

UIView or anywhere in iphone sdk.

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightSwipeHandle:)];
rightRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[rightRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];

//add the your gestureRecognizer , where to detect the touch..
[view1 addGestureRecognizer:rightRecognizer];
[rightRecognizer release];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipeHandle:)];
leftRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[leftRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];

[view1 addGestureRecognizer:leftRecognizer];
[leftRecognizer release];

 - (void)rightSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
 {
     NSLog(@"rightSwipeHandle");
 }

 - (void)leftSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer 
 {
NSLog(@"leftSwipeHandle");
 }
```

I think this the Better solution for your problem

Answer (score 15):

If you're willing to target iPhone OS 3.2 or later (all iPads or updated iPhones), use the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` object. It will do this trivially, which is wickedly cool.